# If leakage current for a diode is 20μA at 20 degrees celsius, what is its value at 40 degrees celsius?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

These are the only values provided so I'm not sure how to go about this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117818/discussion-on-question-by-anti-username-if-leakage-current-for-a-diode-is-20a-a).

Answer (score 2):

Diode leakage current increases with temperature.

Without manufacturer specification, you can only guess using online literature or measure it yourself.

Here is a temperature graph of the leakage over the reverse voltage and temperature for a BAT34 diode:

[image]

You could expect a leakage of about ~60-100uA at 40°C if you have 20uA at 20°C but it may vary significantly.

[Source](https://jeelabs.org/2012/05/27/reverse-diode-current/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is very clearly a learning assignment, and we don't know at which point in understanding diodes you are, it's very hard to help you accurately.

However, what one can definitely say: If you're asked this question, that means you have an equation for the current through a diode (e.g. the Shockley diode equation). That equation will have a temperature dependence. It's usually as simple as writing down that formula and then just changing the temperature-dependent parameter. Not hard!

Comment: Yes I initially tried doing that. But I only have these two values. So do I substitute the others with random values? (I.e. Id, Vd and η)

Comment: you have a formula (or you should be reading your lecture material for one) for a diode current, 100% certainly. I even gave you the name of one to check for – we won't be doing a simple "let me look up this formula" for you. **You** need to learn this stuff, not us. So, please, **edit** your question to include the formula, and show where you'd insert the temperature. Maybe it's easier for us to see where you're stuck there. So far, you're really not explaining where specifically you need help.

Comment: oh ok thank you, I think I understood it now. I just have to use the concept of reverse saturation current doubling for every 10 degree celsius increase in temperature